# Is it required to explicitly delete dynamically allocated containers (like std::vector) in Cython

Tags: python, c, memory-management, garbage-collection, cython

Many Cython STL tests look like this:

```
def simple_test(double x):
    """
    >>> simple_test(55)
    3
    """
    v = new vector[double]()
    try:
        v.push_back(1.0)
        v.push_back(x)
        from math import pi
        v.push_back(pi)
        return v.size()
    finally:
        del v
```

Are `del` statements required there, or would Python's/Cython's reference counting do the job for us?

Comment: The garbage collector will clean it up automatically.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think so. Besides any theoretical considerations (because it's a C object and not a Python object how would pythons gc know when and how to collect it) just running that code produces a memory leak on my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

You need the `del` because `vector` isn't a python class.

## Longer answer

There are a lot of factors that make it impossible for pythons garbage collector to collect that object:

- `vector` instances don't have a reference-count attribute because their class/struct doesn't include `PyObject_HEAD`. It's a C (C++) class so why would it?
- Python objects use `PyObject_GC_New` to make their instance known to the garbage collector and `PyObject_GC_Del` (or `PyObject_GC_UnTrack`) for deletion. However `vector` uses `new` for creation (on the heap) so the garbage collector isn't involved *at all* and thus you need an explicit `del` (I think `delete` should also work, but I haven't checked) for deletion.

This can be seen in the source code as well (I use [ipythons `%%cython`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/config/extensions/cythonmagic.html) so the examples are reproducible):

```
%%cython --cplus

from libcpp.vector cimport vector

def simple_test(double x):
    v = new vector[double]()
    try:
        v.push_back(1.0)
        v.push_back(x)
        from math import pi
        v.push_back(pi)
        return v.size()
    finally:
        del v
```

gives the following (extremly) shortened code in the `.cpp` file (normally this file is located in the `.ipython/cython` folder in your home directory):

```c
  /* "_cython_magic_9df9dbf5f4981f282eb46337245f3bb9.pyx":9
 *     3
 *     """
 *     v = new vector[double]()             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 *     try:
 *         v.push_back(1.0)
 */
  try {
    __pyx_t_1 = new std::vector<double> ();
  } catch(...) {
    [...]
  }
  __pyx_v_v = __pyx_t_1;


  /* "_cython_magic_9df9dbf5f4981f282eb46337245f3bb9.pyx":17
 *         return v.size()
 *     finally:
 *         del v             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 */
  [...]
      {
        delete __pyx_v_v;
      }
```

So without the `del v` there would be no `delete` statement and you would (probably) have a memory leak in your code.

## Practical test

```
%%cython --cplus

from libcpp.vector cimport vector

def simple_test(double x):
    v = new vector[double]()
    for _ in range(20000000):
        v.push_back(x)
    return v.size()
    # NO "del"!!!

import psutil

for _ in range(10):
    simple_test(10)
    print(psutil.virtual_memory().percent)
```

Which prints:

```
47.5
49.4
51.2
53.1
55.1
57.0
58.9
60.8
62.8
65.0
66.9
68.9
70.6
72.5
74.5
76.4
78.4
80.3
82.2
83.6
```

So at least on my computer this leads to ever-increasing memory usage, while the one with `del` does not:

```
%%cython --cplus

from libcpp.vector cimport vector

def simple_test(double x):
    v = new vector[double]()
    try:
        for _ in range(20000000):
            v.push_back(x)
        return v.size()
    finally:
        del v         # this one has a del statement!!!

import psutil

for _ in range(20):
    simple_test(10)
    print(psutil.virtual_memory().percent)
```

Result:

```
47.4
47.4
47.4
47.4
47.4
47.4
47.4
47.4
47.2
47.2
47.2
47.2
47.2
47.2
47.2
47.2
47.2
47.2
47.2
47.3
```

Comment: `%%cython --cplus` I'm curious, is this part of the file in your setup? Or just a comment here?

Comment: @MaxB that's [ipython magic](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/config/extensions/cythonmagic.html). Just load `%load_ext cython` in ipython and you don't need a setup file (the `%%cython` is enough) to test cython code :)

Comment: `You need the del` Didn't expect this TBH (I'm bad at Cython). Good thing I asked. This contradicts my `cython ≈ python` mental model. Having to `del` most of your objects is C-like (C++ generally benefits from RAII w/o the `new`)

Comment: @MaxB Maybe that depends on the compiler (I was using msvc). Cython allows to operate on python objects like you would do in Python and you can also operate on C (or C++) objects but then you need to [(almost) use them like you would in C (or C++)](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html). However it's really great that you can use them in the same function/code but one needs to be careful too.

Comment: Never mind. I was running your second snippet by mistake, the one with del!